# javascript window.location update a get data

Tags: javascript

I have a small javascript issue; I want to reload page with a selected language option value as a get variable.
if I select EN language, the page reload with &lang=EN,
My problem is that I use concat so I get `my_url&lang=EN&lang=FR&lang=SP` ...
so when I select first EN then FR I want to get `my_url&lang=FR` not `my_url&lang=EN&lang=FR`
I want to replace the lang variable not only to add:

```
 <select onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
 <option>DE</option>
 <option>EN</option>
 <option>FR</option>
 <option>SP</option>
 <option>NL</option>
 <option>HR</option>
 <option>PL</option>
 <option>CZ</option>
 </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function handleSelect(elm)
    {
    window.location = window.location.href +"?lang="+elm.value;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function handleSelect(elm)
{
    var href = window.location.href;

    if (href.indexOf("lang") > -1)
    {
        href = href.replace(/(lang)=\w+((?=[&])|)/, "lang="+elm.value);
    }
    else 
    {
        var char = (href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&");

        href+= char + "lang=" + elm.value;
    }

    window.location.href = href;
}
```

It should work with any kind of url keeping the params.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ct4p8pcq/1/). In the fiddle I'm using a `div` instead of the `window.location`.

Comment: Perfect, That was what I need, but I made small changes

Comment: @bourax ok, it would be nice if you update your post with that changes, for future users to see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var currAddress = window.location.href;
var indexOfLang = currAddress.indexOf('lang=');
var tempAddress = currAddress.substring(indexOfLang, indexOfLang+7);
currAddress = currAddress.replace(tempAddress,'lang='+elm.value);
window.location = currAddress;
```

The number 7 is the length of substring - lang=EN.

Comment: the lengh of url is not fix, because there is another variable before language variable that can have different size values.

Comment: I have changed for the any location for the parameter lang.

Comment: This doesnt work, it just replace the location with the variable value

Comment: @bourax, the edit was not correct all the way, have fixed and tested. However, the answer you have marked is more elegant. Leaving this as an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.location = window.location.pathname +"?lang="+elm.value;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Nokolay Kostov- Why do you say it doesnt answer the question? I believe it is the shortest and simplest solution to the question. I see that the accepted solution preserves any additional parameters that may be present, fair enough, but there is no mention of these things in the question

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replace function:

```
window.location = window.location.href.match(/lang=/) ? window.location.replace( /lang=(.*){2}/, 'lang=' + elm.value ) : window.location.href + '?lang=' + elm.value;
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

If `?lang=` exists, replace it with the new one.
If not, just add the lang parameter.

*edit*

I like the `window.location.pathname` solution from Dave Pile, this should be better than checking and replacing something.

*edit2*

```js
var loc = 'http://test.de/?foo=bar'; // window.location.href;
var seperator = loc.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?';
var elm = 'DE';

var url = loc.match(/lang/) ? loc.replace(/lang=(.*){2}/, 'lang' + elm ) : loc + seperator + 'lang=' + elm;
    
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = url;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Look at this snippet, you have to change the `loc` so it should work, also change `var url` to `window.location` and `elm` to your language element.

It checks if parameters exists and change the seperator from `?` to `&`, than if no lang is set, it will set it or if a lang is set, it will replace it.

Comment: Upgraded the solution and added a snippet. You have to adjust it with your parameters, because I used some prepared variables to make it work inside the snippet and don't change the page, but only the url_text so you can see it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function handleSelect(elm)
    {
    var href = window.location.href;
    if (href.indexOf("lang") > -1)
    window.location.href = href.replace(/(lang)=\w+((?=[&])|)/, "lang="+elm.value);
    else 
    window.location = window.location.href +"&lang="+elm.value;
    }
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown he shouldn't edit the solution in the question, but as answer. Through is probably better if he accepted the one that solved his problem.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think so. I have seen many cases when user updates the question with the final solution, and accepts the answer which lead him to it.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown if you see it, fix it. The solution (or answer) to the question should always be along with the other answers, not in the question body.

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well, to not only provide the OP with working code, but also teach him something.